# Freemarker & Intellij "Cannot resolve variable 'myVariable'

Tags: intellij-idea, freemarker

So, I have a set of templates such that one includes others using the #include. In addition, because it is using a complex class as a data source, there are calls to both #assign and #list.

In one case, I have <#list complexClass.variable as myVariable>
Then before there is a </#list> there is an <#include "template2.ftl">

Inside template2.ftl in all cases where there is reference to myVariable it is marked with the underline, and "Inspect Code" reports it as a warning.

If it matters, IntelliJ is 2022.3.2 (Ultimate Edition) Build #U-223.8617.56

I had this with several, and when I entered them into the "freemarker_implicit.ftl" file using @ftlvariable name="..." type="..." All the others have since behaved. No underlines, and no reporting of unresolved variable. I have even moved the line around, thinking perhaps the order may have had something to do with it, but that made no difference.

I went to far as to do an <#assign variableName = myVariable> before the #include and then change the variable name from myVariable to variableName. That made no difference at all. Other than changing the name it said that it couldn't resolve.

For what it is worth, as far as I know, the template works as intended. It is only this warning from IntelliJ about it that shows anything of concern.

Here is a mockup if it helps:

Java Code for the data driving the container.ftl

```
    class Elem {
        String a1;
        Integer b2;
    }
    
    class TempData {
        String value;
        String value2;
        List<Elem> elementList;
    }
```

This is in file named Container.ftl

```
    <#list tempData.elementList as elem>
      <line>${tempData.value}</line>
    
      <#if tempData.value2 != "ABCDEFG">
        <#include "Elements.ftl">
      <#/if>
    </#list>
```

This is in file Elements.ftl
In my situation even though "elem" is defined in the #list of the Container.ftl before this file is #included IntelliJ underlines the "elem" and says that it can't resolve the variable. In reality, it compiles fine and is properly used as evident in the actual output.

```
    <#if elem.a1 == "abc">
        <line>The abc element</line>
    </#if>
    <#if elem.b2 == 7>
        <line>The seven element</line>
    </#if>
```

Comment: Is it possible to attach small project example for investigation?

Comment: I would probably have to create a fake one that can reproduce the issue, because I am not at liberty to share company code.